# Finding the size of datatypes in C ++

Tags: c++

I tried to write a program like this

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a ;//declaration
    a = 12 ;//initialization

    cout<<"size of int"<<size of (a)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the output came like this

```
datatypes.cpp: In function 'int main()':
datatypes.cpp:8:26: error: 'size' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'size_t'?
    8 |     cout<<"size of int"<<size of (a)<<endl;
      |                          ^~~~
      |                          size_t

[Done] exited with code=1 in 17.278 seconds
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: `sizeof`, not `size of`.

Comment: Also: `a = 12;` is not an initialisation. It is an assignment. `int a = 12;` would be initialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `size of ()` function/operator in C++, there is only `sizeof`. C++ doesn't allow names to have spaces.

Note: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

You should change this to:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
// using namespace std; is bad

int main(){
    int a;
    a = 12;
    // sizeof is an operator, so you can do sizeof a.
    // the parentheses aren't actually needed
    // use newline character instead of std::endl
    std::cout <<"size of int" << sizeof (a) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, sizeof isn't a function, it's an operator! The parentheses aren't actually needed. `std::cout << "size is " << sizeof a;` works too.

Comment: @BillLynch -- even more interestingly, the parentheses **are** needed when `sizeof` is applied to a type, but not when it's applied to an expression.